# Go back a few pages when back button pressed

Tags: nsis

I've been trying to figure out how to do that for a few days but no luck. I'm trying to go back a few pages when back button pressed during the installation.

I want to do that in the creater procedure of the page.

```
Page custom printerPage1 verifyPrinterFunc1 ": 1. Printer Bilgileri"
```

Normally I'm able to skip pages during installation by `RelGotoPage` Function.

```
Function RelGotoPage
  IntCmp $R9 0 0 Move Move
  StrCmp $R9 "X" 0 Move
  StrCpy $R9 "3"
Move:
  SendMessage $HWNDPARENT "0x408" "$R9" ""
FunctionEnd
```

But I can't do that in the back button pressed event (E.x. `${NSD_OnBack}`)

I'm stuck and need help from the experienced minds. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
Licensedata "${__FILE__}"
InstallDir $temp
Page directory
Page components
Page license
Page custom printerPage1 verifyPrinterFunc1 ": 1. Printer Bilgileri"

Function onBack
; Go back two pages to the components page
System::Call 'USER32::PostMessage(i$HWNDPARENT,i0x408,i-2,i0)'
Abort
FunctionEnd

Function printerPage1
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_OnBack} onBack
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function verifyPrinterFunc1
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: @Anders What if I want to send user back to previous page using code  ? Please provide solution. Hope you have code for this also. Thnaks

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria This code already does that, just change -2 to -whatever.